# Add a exception to .htaccess rule

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, whmcs

I use the next code to have a full friendly SEO links without .html in link

```
### START - SEO - DO NOT EDIT
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\ ]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L] 
### END - SEO - DO NOT EDIT
```

My problem is with my WHMCS installation, for announcementes knowledgebase link are index.php?rp=title-of-announcement.html and with my rule is redirecting to index.php?rp=title-of-announcement witohout .html and is go tot 404 not found.

How i can solve or add exception of my rule to index.php?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you are checking if `%{THE_REQUEST}` contains `.html`, but that variable contains the full HTTP request line. Replace this with something, that checks against the URL path only. (So for example a RewriteRule that matches paths ending in `.html`, it does not even need a RewriteCond for that.)

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\ ]+)\.html` also matchs `index.php?rp=title-of-announcement.html` . You need another RewriteCond to exclude it from your current rule set. Put this  just bellow the RewriteEngine on `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !\.html$` .